# Do all databases use the USE statement to switch databases?

Tags: php, mysql, database

MySQL uses the `USE database_name` to change the active database. Does that work on all databases?

**EDIT**: By databases I mean DBMS. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: The user that has connected to the server must have proper credentials to the database you want to use.

Comment: Define "all" databases. Some suggestions: ZODB, Tokyo Cabinet, Sybase, Oracle, PostgreSQL, CouchDB, MSSQL, etc. etc.

Comment: I think those are called DBMS's..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on all that are using SQL as a query-language. So that includes, oracle, postgresql, ms sql-server, db2 even ms access. So I think you've got most cases covered.

edit: exclude postgresql - there you have to use \c

Answer (score 0):

No. Postgres uses \c as far as i know. Also, in oracle you will need to use "alter session" command.

Answer (score 0):

No. Many T-SQL databases has the command, but not all. Simple as that.

Comment: @Gambrinus i tried using USE for sqlplus and could get it working. The article you have mentioned required signing in. Can you give the info on how to get it working?

Comment: to access the article without signing in google "oracle use database" and it should be the 2nd result

Comment: Changed my answer, it was a mistake to mention any DB

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not recognize "USE dbname", but instead uses "ATTACH":

```
attach 'my.db' as mydb;
```